# PHP HipHop vs. PHP FastCGI

Tags: php, fastcgi, hiphop

I haven't made any thorough analysis of which implementation of PHP is the best and I haven't found anyone either on the Internet. So, If someone out there just can point out some benefits and flaws regarding each language compared to the other, than I would really appreciate it. Which one compiles the fastest?

**A follow up question:**

Is all programming langauge(languauge that needs to be compiled first) equally fast?

Comment: You mean like is python as fast as php? hard to say. But mostly a language or a framework is not the bottleneck. It more like the architecture of your application, that makes your code run slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HipHop was developed by Facebook to boost the performance on their application. You might know it ;)
HipHop is definetly really fast and it is faster then cgi. But there some minor drwabacks, you have to avoid some functions. See this article on sitepoint.
http://www.sitepoint.com/boost-php-performance-with-hiphop/

Comment: @Pheanotyp: nice article you gave me. I have a follow up question. I would appreciate if you could answer it too

Answer (score 2):

Well I sorry to say that but I feel I must.

No language or compiler will make your application fast. It can add some points, but 99% of time it's programmer's job of tuning an application, being done by hours of profiling, measuring, tuning system settings and stuff.

It's awfully long way to come to the point where such matters would matter. 
One have to ask such a question like yours only with having answers to other questions like these: what's causing your application to runs slow - database daemon? web-serer load? business logic? Same questions for hardware layer: is it memory limits ? CPU power? HDD transer rate? network latency? And thousands others. Without such a background no answer will do any good for you.

I'd say it's rather childish question, "which is fast". It's romantic and all that stuff. But in the real life, it's a pilot who is faster, not a vehicle.